# A Musical Math Rebus

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, rebus

One day left in the fortnightly challenge so I decided to do another musical puzzle.

$\frac{ 066108111111100 }{\lfloor 068097110099101 \rfloor } $

What's the song?

Comment: Great, now I have Tommy Tutone stuck in my head.

Comment: Correct. Not square brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it

> Blood on the Dance Floor

because

> 066108111111100 broken into sets of 3 numbers - 066 108 111 111 100 - then converted to text via ASCII spells *Blood*. Similarly, the denominator spells *Dance* and is wrapped in the *Floor* function.